# Finding duplicate values in row(s) in different tables using linq vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

So I've 2 DataTables like this:

```
table1:    |mean1|mean2|   table2: |mean1|mean2|
           -------------           -------------
           |1.2  | 1.3 |           |2.2  | 1.3 |
           |2.0  | 2.0 | <=======> |2.0  | 2.0 |
           |1.0  | 2.3 |           |3.0  | 1.0 | 
           |1.4  | 2.7 |           |3.0  | 1.2 |
           |1.5  | 2.8 |           |2.7  | 1.3 |
           |2.2  | 1.1 | <=======> |2.2  | 1.1 |
```

My goal is to find values from table2 which are included in table1. It must be written in *VB.Net*

Code for finding duplicates in table1 only looks like:

```
Dim dupes = From row In table1.AsEnumerable()
            Group row By G = New With {.mean1= row.Field(Of Double)("mean1")}.mean1,
            New With {.mean2= row.Field(Of Double)("mean2")}.mean2 Into DupMean = Group
            Where DupMean.Count() > 1
            Select DupMean
```

How can I combine the code with the table2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that

```
Dim dupes = From row In table1.AsEnumerable()
            Join row2 In table2.AsEnumerable()
            On row("mean1") Equals row2("mean1") And row("mean2") Equals row2("mean2")
            Select New With {.RowInT1 = row, .RowEqualInT2 = row2}
```

Or, for include an internal duplicate of each table:

```
Dim dupes = From row In table1.AsEnumerable().Concat(table1.AsEnumerable()()
            Group row By G = New With {.mean1 = row("mean1"), .mean2 = row("mean2")}
            Into DupMean = Group
            Where DupMean.Count() > 1
            Select DupMean
```

Comment: the Field(Of T) Method Unnecessary here, in my opinion.